# Basic MapServer query of PostgreSQL/PostGIS database

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver, query

I've just installed MapServer on a linux server and I am trying to understand how to display a basic map using a PostGIS database. I have displayed a shapefile in the browser, so I know that the mapserver setup works. My mapfile is as follows:

```
MAP

        NAME "sample"
        EXTENT -180 -90 180 90 # Geographic
        SIZE 800 400

        LAYER
          CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
          NAME "roads"
          CONNECTION "user=username password=**** dbname=databasename host=hostdb.com port=5432"
          DATA "geom from public."MLSOA"" 
          STATUS ON
          TYPE LINE
          CLASS
                STYLE
                  COLOR 0 0 0
                END
          END
        END


END # end of map file
```

I then call this by using a url string:

```
http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=/home/user/webapps/htdocs/mapfile_pg.map&layer=roads&mode=map
```

However, I get the error:

```
loadLayer(): Unknown identifier. Parsing error near (MLSOA_London):(line 11)
```

I have also tried calling my database just `MLSOA` and `'MLSOA'`. If I use the line 
`DATA "geom from MLSOA"` I get the following error:

```
msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'roads'. msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error (ERROR: relation "mlsoa" does not exist ) executing query: select encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force_2D("geom"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,"gid" from MLSOA where geom && GeomFromText('POLYGON((-180.225563909774 -90,-180.225563909774 90,180.225563909774 90,180.225563909774 -90,-180.225563909774 -90))',find_srid('','MLSOA','geom'))
```

I think that the problem is with the table name, but I'm not sure how it should be named. Using pgAdminIII, if I want to run a query on this table I use the following syntax:

```
select getsrid(the_geom) from public."MLSOA" limit 10
```

What is the correct syntax for my mapfile?

Comment: HAve you tried using lower case? Maybe DATA behaves as EXPRESSION : http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch05.html#id2634416

Comment: Thanks @unicoletti - that seemed to fix the problem. I did get another problem after that worked with the following error message. I assume that it is unrelated to the upper-case/lower case?

Comment: msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'roads'. msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error (ERROR: find_srid() - couldnt find the corresponding SRID - is the geometry registered in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table? Is there an uppercase/lowercase missmatch? ) executing query: select encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force_2D("the_geom"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,"oid" from public."MLSOA" where the_geom && GeomFromText('POLYGON((-180.225563909774 -90,-180.225563909774 90,180.225563909774 90,180.225563909774 -90,-180.225563909774 -90))',find_srid('','public."MLSOA"','the_geom'))

Comment: @celenius well, the error says it all: to use a postgis table in mapserver it is required that is is registered in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table. This table works as a dictionary/metadata repository fro all postgis-enabled objects in postgres database. Usually the GEOMETRY_SOLUMNS table is automatically updated by the AddGeometryColumn function.
Please see the postgis manual for the manual registration:
http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch04.html#Manual_Register_Spatial_Column

Comment: Thanks @unicoletti - I'm slightly confused why I need to update the `GEOMETRY_COLUMNS`. I imported a projected shapefile using the GUI importer, and just ran `SELECT Probe_Geometry_Columns();` but I still have the same problem. I'll try updating this table manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres naming is case sentitive (it's the only one db that I'm aware of that has this feature) that is why you have to use the double quotes in your query in pgAdmin.

In the .map file Unix-style escaping should work:

```
DATA "geom from public.\"MLSOA\""
```

Manual registration of the geometry column(s) can be performed as documented here:

http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch04.html#Manual_Register_Spatial_Column

Comment: Por performance reason, it is advisable that after the line 'CONNECTION', adding the line PROCESSING "CLOSE_CONNECTION=DEFER". Thus, established database connections will be reused instead of closing them (http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ch05.html, section 5.1.1).

Comment: @dariapra good point, you deserve bonus points ;-)
http://mapserver.org/optimization/vector.html#databases-in-general-postgis-oracle-mysql

Comment: You can't add "`public.`" part, since it results in an error. See [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15937/mapserver-postgis-query-error/15941#15941) for a better `DATA` configuration.