# Mapserver/PostGIS Query Error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, mapserver

I'm having some difficulty understanding the error I am getting from my mapserver/postgis program. I have the following map file:

```
MAP     # start of map file

        NAME "sample"
        EXTENT  82299.5 5002.78 655979.76 657599.55
        SIZE 800 400

        PROJECTION
                "init=epsg:27700"
        END

        LAYER   # layer info
                CONNECTIONTYPE postgis
                NAME "roads
                CONNECTION "user=username 
                password=**** dbname=databasename host=hostdb.com port=5432" 
                DATA "the_geom from public.\"MLSOA\""
                STATUS ON
                TYPE LINE
                 CLASS
                        STYLE
                                COLOR 0 0 0
                        END
                 END
        END    
END     # end of map file
```

I then call this using the following command:

```
http://mysite.com/mapserv.cgi?map=/home/username/webapps/htdocs/mapfile_pg.map&layer=roads&mode=map
```

which gives me the following error:

```
msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'roads'. 
sPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error (ERROR: find_srid() 
- couldnt find the corresponding SRID - is the geometry registered in the 
GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table? Is there an uppercase/lowercase missmatch? ) 
executing query: select encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force_2D("the_geom"),'NDR'),'hex') 
as geom,"oid" from public."MLSOA" where the_geom && GeomFromText
('POLYGON((-180.225563909774 -90,-180.225563909774 
90,180.225563909774 90,180.225563909774 -90,-180.225563909774 
-90))',find_srid('','public."MLSOA"','the_geom'))
```

I asked a [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15924/basic-mapserver-query-of-postgresql-postgis-database) on GIS.SE earlier today about a problem I was having connecting to the DB, and @unicoletti helpfully solved my earlier problem about the database name. However I have now tried all the options that I understand could be causing this current error and have not figured out the problem.

Things that I have tried:

1. Checking that the the table is registered in `GEOMETRY_COLUMNS` (it is, as I could not manually add it as it was there already).
2. Adding in a projection to the Mapserver file
3. Running `SELECT Probe_Geometry_Columns()` to update `GEOMETRY_COLUMNS`
4. Creating an index using the following command: `CREATE INDEX table_the_geom ON "MLSOA" USING GIST ( the_geom );
   CLUSTER table_the_geom ON public."MLSOA";`

Are there any other things that could be causing this error? I'm using PostGreSQL 8.3, PostGIS 1.5.3 and Mapserver 6.0.1. and these programs are all running on a Linux server.

Comment: glad you solved it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sub-query that throws the error ([`Find_SRID`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/Find_SRID.html)) is incorrect:

```
select find_srid('','public."MLSOA"','the_geom')
```

Do you really need to specify the `public` schema in your query? Normally this is part of your `search_path` variable, so you normally don't need it. Try using this in your MAP file:

```
DATA "the_geom from \"MLSOA\" using unique gid using srid=27700"
```

(*Note*: update `gid` with your integer/serial primary key column name, if it is different)

Comment: Thanks Mike, that worked. You are correct, I did not need `public` in my query.