# Mapserver doesn't load geography columns of PostGIS

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I have installed Mapserver 7.4.0 with PostGIS 2.4. However, I can't load any layer with `geography` column.
This is my MAP file (with contents prior to `LAYER` omitted):

```
MAP
<omitted>

  LAYER
    COMPOSITE
    END # COMPOSITE
    CONNECTION "host=127.0.0.1 dbname=testgis user=postgres password=****** port=5432"
    CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
    DATA "geog from srwg"
    METADATA
      "coordsys_name"   "Longitude-Latitude / WGS 84"
    END # METADATA
    NAME "New Layer"
    PROJECTION
      "proj=longlat"
      "datum=WGS84"
      "no_defs"
    END # PROJECTION
    STATUS ON
    TEMPLATE "query"
    TILEITEM "location"
    TYPE POLYGON
    UNITS METERS
    CLASS
      NAME "Class (0)"
      STYLE
        COLOR 255 255 255
        OUTLINECOLOR 0 0 0
        SIZE 8
      END # STYLE
    END # CLASS
  END # LAYER

END # MAP
```

It comes with the following error:

```
msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error executing query
```

Is Mapserver incompatible with `geography` columns?

Comment: Didn't try myself, but it should work: https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.4/ch06.html#idm2922

Comment: @AndreasMüller It doesn't work. New error: msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Error (Error:  find_srid() - could not find the corresponding SRID - is the geometry registered in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table?  Is there an uppercase/lowercase mismatch? (Note: It still treats the layer as `geometry` and try to find it in `GEOMETRY_COLUMNS` table)

Comment: A similar question here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/15941/46073

Comment: @AndreasMüller Did you try it yourself? I hope you did.

Comment: If I had a solution for you, i would give an answer. Unfortunately i didn't use the geographic data type with mapserver. In my first link it is claimed that mapserver supports geographic columns, in my second link, which i searched for you, there seems to be an answer, using a differnt data entry with a trailing `using srid=`, so i hoped it may work for you.

Comment: `DATA "geog FROM geogtable USING SRID=4326 USING UNIQUE gid"`  is posed as the solution, but that's problematic if you say that geography columns are WGS 84 longlat, because EPSG:4326 is latlong (EPSG registry WKT ~ http://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326)